# Is it possible to encode 10 digit mobile number into 4char and reverse?

Tags: c#, encoding, logic, decode, encode

I need to encode 10 digit mobile number into 4 or 6 digit text/number and also want to decode in same 10 digit number.

Comment: You can effectively use 6 bits of the ASCII character set to encode numbers, without causing problems in transmission.  This means that the 40 bits of the 10-digit number could be encoded into 7 characters.  And you can do a little better if you encode centesimal digits, or if you make use of "entropy" (forbidden sequences) in the 10-digit number.

Comment: 10 digits in centesimal would be 7*5 = 35.  This should encode into 6 characters using Base64 encoding.